# Prior expected ratios of influence of the data to influence of the prior

Tags: bayesian, prior

Suppose for every measurable set $A\subseteq [0,+\infty),$
$$
\Pr(\Lambda \in A) = \int_A e^{-\lambda/\mu} \left( \frac{d\lambda} \mu \right)
$$
so $\Lambda$ has an exponential distribution with expected value $\mu.$ And suppose
$$
X\mid \Lambda \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\Lambda).
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\Pr(X=x) & = \operatorname E\left( \frac{\Lambda^x e^{-\Lambda}}{x!} \right) = \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} \right) e^{-\lambda/\mu} \left( \frac {d\lambda} \mu \right) \\[10pt] & = \left( \frac \mu {\mu+1} \right)^x \frac 1 {\mu+1} = q^x p \quad \text{for } x\in\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}, \text{where } p+q=1,
\end{align}
so $X$ has a geometric distribution and
$$
\operatorname E(X) = \frac{1-p} p = \frac q {1-q} = \mu. \tag 1
$$ 
This is a standard exercise, so I wonder why I never thought to find the conditional distribution of $\Lambda$ given $X$ until recently. I found this:
$$
\Pr(\Lambda\in A \mid X=x) = \frac 1 {x!}\int_A \left( \frac \lambda q \right)^x e^{-\lambda/q} \left( \frac {d\lambda} q \right)
$$
i.e. a gamma distribution with "shape" parameter $x+1,$ and so
$$
\operatorname E(\Lambda \mid X=x) = (x+1) q \quad \text{with $q$ as in line $(1)$ above},
$$
I felt disinclined to believe this answer. Where we had $\mu>0$ as the scale parameter, we now have $q\in(0,1).$ No matter how big $\mu$ is, it gets squashed down to something less than $1.$

Thus **the data overwhelms the prior after just one observation, and the mere fact that $\mu$ is very big tells us, before we see the data, that that will almost certainly happen.**

- What is known about prior expected ratios of influence of the data to influence of the prior?
- What is the practical import of answers to the question above?
- Does it somehow tell us that the particular prior we've chosen makes sense, or doesn't?